# How to add annotations to PDF using DITA-OT

Tags: annotations, pdf-generation, dita, dita-ot

I need to create a PDF from DITA with annotations embedded.  Are there hooks in PDF2 to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the docs of the `args.draft` parameter ([DITA-OT - Common Parameters](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.3/parameters/parameters-base.html)) and the [Generating PDF comments using args.draft=yes](https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic11156.html)  XML forum post.

Comment: I think some clarification is needed. If by "annotations" you mean DITA draft-comments, the args.draft parameter should turn them on. But if you mean adding PDF annotations like PDF comments, I don't think pdf2 supports those. Maybe your PDF processor (Antenna House, XEP, etc) supports them. It's probably custom work.